# Bind component state with Apollo local state

Tags: apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I want to use Apollo local state to keep the information to track if the user logged in or not.

So I modified the Apollo client with clientState as follows.

```
clientState: {
    defaults: {
      loggedIn: 'false',
    },
    resolvers: {
      Mutation: {
        toggleLoggedIn(_: any, variables: any, { cache }: any) {
          // read the cart open value from the cache
          const { loggedIn } = cache.readQuery({
            query: LOGIN_STATE_QUERY,
          });
          const data = {
            data: {
              loggedIn: !loggedIn,
            },
          };
          cache.writeData(data);
          return data;
        },
      },
    },
  },
```

I am planning to use two routers for my application.
 and

so that here is my application state.

App.js file

```
const { loading, user } = this.state;

<ApolloProvider client={client}>
  {user ? <AppRouter /> : <SessionRouter />}
</ApolloProvider>
```

State of the app.js file

```
this.state = {
      loading: true,
      user: null,
};
```

What I want to do is bind the state of the app component with the apollo local state. so that mutating the local state "loggedIn" variable will rerender with the related router (Session router or Approuter)

if there is ambiguity in this question please feel free to ask in the comments.

Comment: Is there a query or mutation for logging in? Or for requesting the currently logged in user?

Comment: Yes. There is a login mutation. what it does is updating the  apollo local state loggedIn variable to true on correct login information.  as the local state variable changes app should re render to the correct router. what i want is to bind apollo-local state logggedIn variable with my app components state variable user

Comment: I may lack the context to fully understand your use case, but managing a separate `loggedIn` state through `apollo-link-state` **and** a `user` state through component state seems superfluous. If we want to know "is the user logged in" and render either `AppRouter` or `SessionRouter` accordingly, it seems like you could just check whether the user exists in the cache, either with the `Query` component or by using the `readQuery`/`readFragment` methods of the client instance.

Comment: I agree with Daniel Rearden. I don't see the benefits of storing the state in React state and the apollo cache. 

Another small critque - You also don't need to use ApolloProvider there. Instead, you should just the Query component with the @client directive.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to bind Apollo state to component state, you could do the following:

Create a container component that performs the local state query. When the local state query receives the data, render the child component with said data as a prop.

```
class container extends React.Component {
render() {
  return (
    <Query query={login_query}>
      {(data, loading) => {
        if(loading) return;
        return <LoginComponent data={data} />
      }}
  )
}
}
```